# SublimeText will not let me type a curly bracket for an if-else conditional with a single statement

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, code-formatting

**Background**

I am taking a computer programming course.  I've used SublimeText off and on for a few years but not enough to know about all of its knobs and switches.

**My Workflow**

I download the code sample from the book and run it through `cpplint`.  I reformat the sample code to make `cpplint` happy for the most part.

**My Problem**

When I come across a `if-else` statement, I can't type a curly at the end of the `if` (or the following `else`).  Take, for instance, this section of code:

```
if (length == 0) 
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
else
{
    loc = seqSearch(removeItem);

    if (loc != -1)
        removeAt(loc);
    else
        cout << "The item to be deleted is not in the list."
             << endl;
}
```

Even though I know I'm not *required* to format it as such, I want to change the format so that a run through `cpplint` is clean.

```
if (length == 0) {  <--- add this "{"
    cout << "Cannot delete from an empty list." << endl;
} else {            <--- and put "else" on the same line as "{" and "}"
...
```

When I put my cursor at the end of the line `if (length == 0)`, I can't type a `{`.  The following message is all I see in the console (after enabling debugging):

```
command: wrap_block {"begin": "{", "end": "}"}
```

I have to go through many steps to get a bracket where I want the bracket.  Adding one ahead of time before the `else` does not allow me to put one after the `if` conditional (e.g. `if (length == 0) {`).  ST also prevents me from typing one after the `else`, but I can type one before the `else`.

For example:

```
if (location < 0 || location >= length) <--- I can't type a "{" here
    cout << "The location of the item to be "
         << "replaced is out of range." << endl;
else       <-------------------------------- nor here
    list[location] = repItem;
```

**In Summary**

If I type fresh bits of code by hand, I can type a `{` where I want one.  However, if there is an `if-else` already there and it doesn't have curly braces, adding a `{` after an `if` or `else` is prohibited.  I fear that I'm going to have to disable the auto-pairing feature of ST to correct this.

**Question**

What can I do to resolve this issue and be allowed to put braces where I want them?

**Details About My Setup**

macOS 10.12.6 (Sierra) and SublimeText version 3

Packages that are installed:

- "Git"
- "GitGutter"
- "Package Control"
- "SideBarEnhancements"

[image: Four packages are shown when I go to Package Control::List Packages]

Contents of "Settings" > "Preferences.sublime-settings User":

```
{
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Light).tmTheme",
"draw_white_space": "all",
"font_size": 12,
"ignored_packages":
[
    "Vintage"
],
"rulers":
[
    80
],
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true
}
```

Comment: I've tried multiple combinations and I can't reproduce the problem you are describing;    Adding a starting curly brace adds the ending brace in exactly the right spot, and at no point was I unable to type the character.  are you *absolutely sure* you don't have any other plugins installed?

Comment: If I go to Preferences > Package Control > list packages, those are the only four that are listed.  I'll include a screenshot.

Comment: A curious problem indeed; the command that's executing is the correct one for the situation (as a built in) but I've never encountered that situation before. None of those installed packages seem like likely culprits. Are there any `py` files in your `User` package?

Comment: I have "Settings", "Settings - Syntax Specific", "Settings - Distraction Free".  If I open up Settings, I have two files - "Preferences.sublime-settings Default" and "Preferences.sublime-settings User".  I've edited my post to include my user settings.

Comment: Did you check what are the packages that you have installed? In my case i had this package installed and when I removed it, it started working properly again --> Sublime-HTMLPrettify

Comment: @AhmedAziz it was an installed package that prevented this from behaving as expected.  It was a long time ago so I don't recall exactly _which_ package but if you submit this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check what are the packages that you have installed? In my case i had this package installed and when I removed it, it started working properly again --> Sublime-HTMLPrettify